# Python read binary file of unsigned 16 bit integers

Tags: python, binary, format

I must read a binary file in Python, and store its content in an array. The information I have on this file is that

```
filename.bin is of size 560x576 (height x width) with 16 b/p, i.e., unsigned 16-bit integer for each pixel
```

This is what I have been able to come up with so far:

```
import struct
import numpy as np
fileName = "filename.bin"

with open(fileName, mode='rb') as file: 
    fileContent = file.read()



a = struct.unpack("I" * ((len(fileContent)) // 4), fileContent)

a = np.reshape(a, (560,576))
```

However I get the error

```
cannot reshape array of size 161280 into shape (560,576)
```

161280 is exactly half of `560 x 576 = 322560`. I would like to understand what I am doing wrong and how to read the binary file and reshape in the required form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using 'I' for the format which is 32 bit unsigned instead of 'H' which is 16 bit unsigned.

Do this

```
a = struct.unpack("H" * ((len(fileContent)) // 2), fileContent)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Just to see if I understood: if instead my file was 560 x 576, 32-bit signed integer per pixel, what I would have to use is `struct.unpack("i" * ((len(fileContent)) // 4), fileContent)' , right?

Comment: Yes, but with a capital I for unsigned. Small i is signed.